# How to place div container inside another div container, within a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

Totally baffled because this should be so simple.  I have a jquery tab structure.  Within the first tab I've inserted a div container that appears as a yellow box.  Inside this yellow box div I'm trying to insert a div. container that appears as a red box.

But I can't get the red box to appear inside the yellow box.  I've tried the usual positioning and z-index, etc but strangely nothing works.  I think I've become blind to the obvious.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k1kphcm8/

```js
$('.tabs-nav a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('.tab-active').removeClass('tab-active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('tab-active');
  $('.TabContainerClass div').hide();
  $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(300)
});

$('.tabs-nav a:first').trigger('click'); // Default
```

```css
.tabs-nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tabs-nav .tab-active a {
  background: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: white;
  border-top-color: darkorange;
  border-left-color: darkorange;
  border-right-color: darkorange;
}
.tabs-nav a {
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: darkorange;
  border-right-color: #C9C9C9;
  background: #E6E6E6;
  color: #7A7A7A;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 122px;
}
.tabs-nav li {
  float: left;
}
.TabContainerClass {
  width: 491px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid darkorange;
  border-top: 0;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
.YellowDivClass {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.RedDivClass {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="tabs-nav">
  <li class="tab-active"><a href="#YellowDiv" rel="nofollow">Countries</a> 
  </li>

  <li class=""><a href="#tab-2" rel="nofollow">Year</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-3" rel="nofollow">Materials</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-4" rel="nofollow">Products</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div class="TabContainerClass">

  <div id="YellowDiv" class="YellowDivClass">
    <div id="RedDiv" class="RedDivClass"></div>
  </div>


  <div id="tab-2" style="display: none;">
    <p>This is TAB 2</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab-3" style="display: none;">
    <p>This is TAB 3.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab-4" style="display: none;">
    <p>This is TAB 4.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide all the *inactive* tabs you are using:

```
$('.TabContainerClass div').hide();
```

which hides *all* the divs inside `TabContainerClass` which is not intended. Instead use this to hide only the *direct children* of `TabContainerClass`:

```
$('.TabContainerClass > div').hide();
```

[**`UPDATED FIDDLE`**](https://jsfiddle.net/b8oxzufm/)

```js
$('.tabs-nav a').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $('.tab-active').removeClass('tab-active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('tab-active');
  $('.TabContainerClass > div').hide();
  $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(300)
});

$('.tabs-nav a:first').trigger('click'); // Default
```

```css
.tabs-nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.tabs-nav .tab-active a {
  background: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-color: white;
  border-top-color: darkorange;
  border-left-color: darkorange;
  border-right-color: darkorange;
}
.tabs-nav a {
  border-width: 0px 1px 1px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: darkorange;
  border-right-color: #C9C9C9;
  background: #E6E6E6;
  color: #7A7A7A;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 122px;
}
.tabs-nav li {
  float: left;
}
.TabContainerClass {
  width: 491px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid darkorange;
  border-top: 0;
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}
.YellowDivClass {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 30px 0px 0px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.RedDivClass {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="tabs-nav">
  <li class="tab-active"><a href="#YellowDiv" rel="nofollow">Countries</a> 
  </li>

  <li class=""><a href="#tab-2" rel="nofollow">Year</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-3" rel="nofollow">Materials</a>
  </li>
  <li class=""><a href="#tab-4" rel="nofollow">Products</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div class="TabContainerClass">

  <div id="YellowDiv" class="YellowDivClass">
    <div id="RedDiv" class="RedDivClass"></div>
  </div>


  <div id="tab-2" style="display: none;">
    <p>This is TAB 2</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab-3" style="display: none;">
    <p>This is TAB 3.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tab-4" style="display: none;">
    <p>This is TAB 4.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: very well spotted.  Much appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem one of your selectors. You are hiddding every div element instead of hidden only direct div elements. So instead of `$('.TabContainerClass div').hide();`. You should have `$('.TabContainerClass > div').hide();`